# Calculating age from DOB extracted from database

Tags: java, sql

I have this code which I am using to calculate age from DOB.But I am not sure whether it is working properly or not as when I am calling this function from another file, I am not able to see any output.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getEmployeeAge() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ArrayList<Integer> employeeage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            LibraryConnection lc = new LibraryConnection(library, dbConnection);


            rs = lc.executeQuery("GetEmployeeAge", null);


            while(rs.next()){   
/*              QuartReport qcd = new QuartReport();

                qcd.setYear(rs.getInt(1));
                qcd.setQuarter(rs.getInt(2));
                qcd.setCount(rs.getInt(3));
*/

                String dob = rs.getString(1);

                int yearDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(6, 10));
                int monthDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(3, 5));
                int dayDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(0, 2));

                //CALCULATE THE CURRENT YEAR, MONTH AND DAY
                //INTO SEPERATE VARIABLES
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                int thisYear = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
                date = new java.util.Date();
                int thisMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                date = new java.util.Date();
                int thisDay = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

                //CREATE AN AGE VARIABLE TO HOLD THE CALCULATED AGE
                //TO START WILL – SET THE AGE EQUEL TO THE CURRENT YEAR MINUS THE YEAR
                //OF THE DOB
                int age = thisYear - yearDOB;
                //IF THE CURRENT MONTH IS LESS THAN THE DOB MONTH
                //THEN REDUCE THE DOB BY 1 AS THEY HAVE NOT HAD THEIR
                //BIRTHDAY YET THIS YEAR
                if(thisMonth < monthDOB){
                age = age -1;
                }

                //IF THE MONTH IN THE DOB IS EQUEL TO THE CURRENT MONTH
                //THEN CHECK THE DAY TO FIND OUT IF THEY HAVE HAD THEIR
                //BIRTHDAY YET. IF THE CURRENT DAY IS LESS THAN THE DAY OF THE DOB
                //THEN REDUCE THE DOB BY 1 AS THEY HAVE NOT HAD THEIR
                //BIRTHDAY YET THIS YEAR
                if(thisMonth == monthDOB && thisDay < dayDOB){
                age = age -1;
                }

                employeeage.add(age);
            }

            return employeeage;
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            SqlUtils.close(rs);
        }


        return null;
    }
```

The xml query that I am executing is:

```
<s:query name="GetEmployeeAge" xmlns:s="http://www.slamb.org/axamol/sql-library/statement">
<s:sql databases="mysql">
SELECT DOB(`Date Of Birth`) 
FROM `Employee` LEFT JOIN Employee-Detail ON `Employee.MRN` = `Employee-Detail.MRN`
GROUP BY DOB(`Date Of Birth`)
ORDER BY DOB(`Date Of Birth`) ASC
</s:sql>
</s:query>
```

Can anyone help me in pointing what might be the reason for this?

**UPDATE1:** The SQL query is working correctly.I executed it on MySQL workbench and it is returning the result in this format `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`

**UPDATE2:** I am using the result of this to generate a graph whose details are present at [Generating Histogram through Java and PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093641/generating-histogram-through-java-and-primefaces)

Comment: Use JodaTime, convert the value from the database to a DateTime object

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your statement that you "are not able to see any output".  Was there some logging or System.out statements in your code that I am missing?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The problem is that I have restriction in using API's.The system dosen't support it.Can you look at the code and help me out by pointing if there is any mistake?

Comment: @mattforsythe I am calling this function which is then using it to generate graph and I am not getting any output visible and not error or exception thrown

Comment: Separation of concerns would help you a bunch here: if the method did not pull DOBs from the database _and_ calculate related ages, then you could simply unit test the method that calculates age given a DOB.

Comment: So, tell us what IS being returned.  An empty ArrayList?  An ArrayList with just one element?  The fact that you can't use the output to generate a graph probably means there's something wrong with your graphing method; not something wrong with the age calculation.

Comment: OK, I see your update.  So your earlier question was that nothing was being displayed when you tried to draw a graph.  This question here is that nothing is being displayed when you try to draw a graph.  Why do you think that there's anything wrong with the age calculation?

Comment: I tried to figure out the graphing part first but couldn't find any issue with it.So, I thought that there might be error in age calculation

Comment: So, test the age calculation directly, without using the graphing stuff.  It's really not a good idea to post a Stack Overflow question claiming there's a problem with some code, when you don't know whether there's a problem with it or not.

Comment: @DavidWallace I never claimed that there's a problem with the code.I mentioned that I am not able to identify why no output is coming

Comment: OK, well the best idea I have for you is to test your code, and EITHER delete or update your question when you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is the fact that a year and a month are not a whole number, this is why we suggest using a library which is been properly designed to handle these weirdnesses...like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)...

A year has 365.242 days which makes a month 30.436 (approximately) days long...:P

```
public class DateOfBirth {

    public static final double DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365.242;
    public static final double DAYS_IN_MONTH = DAYS_IN_YEAR / 12d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int day = 8;
        int month = 3;
        int year = 1972;

        // Number of days...
        double time = toDays(year, month, day);
        // One day less of the year 2015...
        double today = toDays(2014, 4, 16); // today...

        double diff = today - time;

        int years = (int)Math.round(diff / DAYS_IN_YEAR);
        double over = diff % DAYS_IN_YEAR;
        int months = (int)(over / DAYS_IN_MONTH);
        over = over % DAYS_IN_MONTH;
        int days = (int) over;

        System.out.println(years + " years, " + months + " months, " + days + " days");           
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(diff / DAYS_IN_YEAR));            
    }

    public static double toDays(int year, int month, int day) {            
        return (year * DAYS_IN_YEAR) + (month * DAYS_IN_MONTH) + day;            
    }

}
```

This outputs...

```
42 years, 1 months, 7 days
42.105
```

Now, the problem with this, is you will get all sorts of strange rounding errors, so it is, at best, a guess...